# re-numbering list members in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

How can re-numbering list members respectively from zero to n in Python ?

for example :

```
In : [4, 10, 12, 40, 4, 12, 20, 21]

Out : [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: What is the logic? Don't throw numbers and make us guess what you need.

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ: There's no indication here that sorting has anything to do with it.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: No, if that were the case, 40 wouldn't go to 3.

Comment: My guess about the logic is, we go from left to right, start with counter 0, if it is not previously seen in the input list, add counter value to output and increment counter, otherwise if seen previously, add the counter value corresponding to the item in previous case.

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev good guess, but still a guess. We should not be in the condition to guess.

Comment: Another guess: OP always wants `[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 4, 5]` as output regardless of what is in input.

Comment: Well I just put it on hold, Now the OP will not make us guess anymore :)

Comment: I agree with you that the OP is definitely not giving a clear explanation of what is wanted, but come on the example given is very easy to understand... Each element in Out corresponds to the first index where the element of the same index in In was encountered...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go, the solution for your problem

```
x=[4, 10, 12, 40, 4, 12, 20, 21]
y=[0]
nextIndex=1;
for i in (range(1,len(x))):
    for j in range(i):
        if(x[i]==x[j]):
            y.append(y[j])
            break
        if(j==i-1):
            y.append(nextIndex)
            nextIndex+=1
print(y)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 4, 5]
```

Basically what the user is trying is to get a same index for repeated integer and assigning new one for new integer

@Rafat try to be more clear with your questions next time.

Comment: Your solution works, however you make use of two for loops and two if tests, which can definitely be broken down to one for loop and one if test. It would also be interesting to see if a list comprehension solution is possible.